# Using redis as a DB for some values

Tags: node.js, redis

I notice that all the examples of redis contains key-value option.

For example:

```
key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 value3
```

But my DB is more complex, and I wish to support some values of keys.

```
key1 createday1 deleteday1 size1
key2 createday2 deleteday2 size2
key3 createday3 deleteday3 size3
```

Also, I wish to sort the DB by its createday, for example.

Is redis support it?

Comment: Yes, you can use a sorted set: http://redis.io/commands/ZADD. Check out data types http://redis.io/topics/data-types

Comment: @agconti: I try zadd on this set: `[ 'guid',
  'key10',
  'cachetime',
  '8/6/2015 @ 13:36:33',
  'persistenttime',
  undefined,
  'size',
  undefined]`
and it gives me the following error: `Error: ERR syntax error`

Comment: Actually you need to read Redis manual :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the data in a hash, and create indices using sorted sets.

For example:

```
HSET key1 createday value
HSET key1 size value
```

And so on.

For example, to sort on createday, store it as a Unix timestamp. On adding the entry, also add the ID of the entry (key1 in your example) to a sorted set with the timestamp as the score. Now you can get ranges and decide which order to sort by - ascending or descending. Use this index as a list of matching keys which you can then operate on.

Do this "index" for each value you may want to sort on.